# Is there a GNU Windows based text editor that uses full regex with great documentation for find replace?

Tags: regex, windows, windows-7, text-editor

I tried Notepad++ but it has close to no documentation and is missing many regex features.  Visual studio 2010 is pretty good but it is also missing features.

Comment: I think gedit supports that but Im not sure..

Comment: I apologize to leaving off the [Windows] Tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [EditPad Pro.](http://www.editpadpro.com/) It's not free (although neither is full VS), but it's an excellent editor.

I haven't personally tested all the regex support, but according to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/editpadpro.html), it's compatible with Perl (regex standard?), Java and .NET regex styles.

Comment: Too great of a product to complain it's not free....most amazing search and replace I've ever used!

Answer (score 3):

try [VIM](http://www.vim.org/) if you'r not afraid of having to learn new things...

- [Here is good resource to start learning VIM way :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843913/looking-for-a-vim-book)
- [Here is good tutorial/book](http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Vim_en:Table_of_Contents)

Comment: I usually have a quick reference card around. It's not easy to remember all the features of vim. I'm using this [one](http://tnerual.eriogerg.free.fr/vim.html) but there are plenty to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

The [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com) programmer's editor supports *perl compatible regular expression* but it is not free.

But there is also a free [Zeus Lite](http://www.zeusedit.com/lite) version and it has the same regular expression feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, TextWrangler has a pretty good regex search/replace. Haven't struck any limitations yet. It's free, or you can pay for it's bigger brother BBEdit

http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/